# How do I turn off the spell-check in Google Chrome on OSX?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, spell-check

As documented [here](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95604?hl=en), Google Chrome has an automatic spell-check built in, and it is possible to disable it for certain fields temporarily.

Can it be disabled for all sites?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On OS X the checkbox is now under Edit -> Spelling and Grammar. Note that the browser must be focused on a text box for the menu entry to be enabled.

On my system the checkbox appeared as set only after I restarted Chrome. The red lines disappeared immediately as I unchecked it.

[image: disable spellchecking]

Comment: Wonderful, thank you - the trick of focusing on the text box to get the option to enable is key.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `chrome://settings/languages` in the address bar

A dialogue box will open listing the installed languages.

At the bottom is a tickbox labelled `Enable Spell Checking`.

Untick the box.  This should disable spell checking everywhere.

[image: Screenshot of dialogue]

Comment: What if I don't have that checkbox???

Comment: Damn! The tickbox disappeared in version 47.

Comment: -1 same reason: this answer does not apply to OSX.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Chrome Settings (Enter `chrome://settings/` in address bar)

Click on Advance Settings and then click on `Language and Input settings` and then untick the `Enable spell checking` check box.

Comment: I can't see that option. I'm on Chrome 38 on OSX. Perhaps it's different on Windows?

Comment: -1 The question is for OSX. This answer doesn't apply on macs.